# Como inicializar um vetor de string dentro de uma struct?

Tags: c++, string

Preciso iniciar uma lista com nomes de pessoas no início do meu programa e estou tentando inicializar os nomes em uma string dentro da minha `struct`, desse jeito:

```
char* nomes[100] = {"gabriel" , "vanessa"};
```

porém estou recebendo esse erro: "Muitos valores de inicializadores", tentei inicializar fora da struct também mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando tentei compilar esse código recebi o seguinte erro: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'.

Esse valores { "gabriel", "vanessa" } criam uma matriz de matriz do tipo const char*.

O ponteiro nomes precisa ser do tipo const char* para apontar para essa matriz.

Quando o programa estiver em execução, cada elemento é copiado para uma matriz do tipo char[100], o que permite a modificação de cada elemento separadamente.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char* nomes[100] = { "gabriel", "vanessa" };

  std::cout << nomes[0] << '\n';
  std::cout << nomes[1] << '\n';

  nomes[0] = "vanessa";
  nomes[1] = "gabriel";

  std::cout << nomes[0] << '\n';
  std::cout << nomes[1] << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu não vi qualquer problema, pode ser a configuração do compilador que está usando.

Mas se está usando C++ então use o tipo `string` e não um *array* de `char`. Melhor ainda, use um `vector` para armazenar as `string`s:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *nomes[100] = { "gabriel" , "vanessa" };
    string aNomes[] = { "gabriel" , "vanessa" };
    vector<string> vNomes = { "gabriel" , "vanessa" };
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IJfQ9O). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/VectorStringscpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Strings.cpp).

Se não fizer assim e não tiver um bom motivo está apenas programando em C no compilador do C++ e provavelmente aprendendo errado.